# How do I generate empty files, with names randomly taken from an input text file?

Tags: bash

I would like to generate 20 files (empty), each named using a 10 character string chosen randomly from a file "test.txt"(manually generate the file test.txt).

How to do this task?

Comment: We don't do your homework ... you have to figure that out your self. Or at least show what you have tried, and how it worked / failed.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you – what did you try and where do you have problems? Please [edit] to add further information.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have the strings in `test.txt`, and they are all 10 characters wide, and they are one per line:

```
shuf -n 20 test.txt | xargs touch
```

`shuf` will shuffle the contents of `test.txt` and print the first 20 lines, then `xargs` will take that output and convert it to arguments for `touch`, which will create files using those arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Using just the bash, without any external commands:

```bsh
mapfile names < test.txt # save filenames in array
for ((i = 0; i < 20; i++)) # loop 20 times
do
    ind=$((RANDOM % ${#names[@]}))  # take random value less than length of array
    > "${names[$ind]}"      # redirection creates empty file
    unset names[$ind]       # remove used filename from array
    names=( "${names[@]}" ) # recreate array to remove gaps
done
```